# Get unwrapped value on tap gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

I have a SwiftUI view which accepts a `codeToVerify` state binding, and contains a `TextField` with which the user checks a property associate with the code.

I am not sure why, but when I set a breakpoint and check the value of `codeToVerify`, the value comes back as it is initially set when declared, despite the `TextField` accepting the binding and working as expected otherwise.

This is what I am currently trying, though I have tried a bunch of variations. This function is called by a parent View's `NavigationLink` so I am providing a default value of `""`.

I would appreciate your thoughts on why this might not be working, and what I can do to fix it.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct BusinessVerifyCode: View {
    @State var codeToVerity:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(text: self.$codeToVerify, ..)
            Button(..)
            .onTapGesture {
                print(self.$codeToVerity.wrappedValue) // Always returns ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: XCode debug]
[image: UI capture (with sensible chuckle)]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should be used. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

```
struct BusinessVerifyCode: View {
    @State var codeToVerity:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Placeholder", text: self.$codeToVerity)
            Button("Tap") { // use own button action
                print(self.codeToVerity)  // get state directly
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, you are everywhere!  The problem turned out to be that in my real code I implemented TextField via TextFieldUI and did not update `text` in the updater function within.